# Execute a command from a buffer

Tags: shell, shell-command

Say, you create a new buffer (Fundamental), type a shell command and want it executed. Like you can do in a `*scratch*` buffer with lisp code (`C-x C-e`). Or you have a text file, that has text interspersed with shell commands. Or a shell script, and you want to execute one of the commands. Is there a way?

Or maybe you have an url in a buffer, and you want to do `xdg-open URL`. Or a path to a directory, and you want `ls DIR`. Is this possible? Maybe, like, `M-! xdg-open` , and then somehow paste the url into the minibuffer?

Comment: Check out  [Working with source code](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html#Working-with-Source-Code) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: If you have a URL in a buffer, you can just run `M-x browse-url-at-point`.